# when was this released? com.github.play2war.ext » redirect-playlogger_2.10

Tags: scala, maven, playframework-2.2

Could someone tell me when the latest one became available (i.e. was it last year or this year..)? Or tell me how to check on the Maven website to get this info?

com.github.play2war.ext » redirect-playlogger_2.10

com.github.play2war.ext » redirect-playlogger_2.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last update **03-Jan-2013**

Source: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/play2war/ext/ (There are dates next to each file) ;)